# Using session key of Django session as foreign key

Tags: mysql, django, session

I have used session in Django and this resulted in creation of table `django_session` in MySQL. I want to use the `session_key` of this table as foreign key in other MySQL tables. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Later on you can get session key of interest from your objects like the following:

```
my_model_object.session.session_key
```

Comment: can u tell in detail?? i want to associate session_key with other mysql tables so that when session_key is deleted data in all other tables are deleted automatically.

Comment: It will behave the way you want it by default: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: the table mymodel is empty when user logs in..whereas a row is created in django_session table

Comment: Of course it is. You will have to create rows there youself whenever you need them with the data associated.

Comment: @AlexPavlenko `on_delete` is now required, see my edit to the answer.

Comment: How do I populate this field when creating a new object?

Comment: Depends on your needs. If you are doing in the view - something like `MyModel(session_id=request.session.session_key)` should suffice.